# Retrieving images from tables in mysql and running a base64 to decode them before writing to filesystem

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, base64

I need help. I'm stumped.

I'm trying to pull the latest image stored in a blob from 5 tables, apply base64 on them before saving them as images. my code below.

My initial problem is I cannot seem to pass the variable tableId into the mysql query.

The table names are 100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005
The table columns are identical with the 'image' column containing the blobs and 'Time' column containing timestamps values.

```
#!/bin/bash

total=5 #value to increment the devices
tablecount=100000
    for ((i=1; i<=$total; i++))
    do
tableId=$(($tablecount + $i))
echo ${image} | base64 -d > images/$tableID.jpg
done < <(echo "SELECT image, Time FROM table_'$tableID' ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;" | mysql mydb -u someuser -pPassword)
```

Comment: Sorry I meant the last row in the table. I'm trying to retrieve the latest image blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes, they will stop the shell from expanding text. Also you need to execute your query inside the loop.

```
for ((i=1; i<=$total; i++))
do
    tableId=$(($tablecount + $i))
    echo "SELECT image FROM table_$tableID ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;" | mysql -sN -u someuser -pPassword mydB | base64 -d > "file$tableId.jpg"
done
```

I also emoted the time column and make sure mysql command does not print headers or tables.

Here is test code and result for the loop part:

```sh
$ bash t.sh
SELECT image FROM table_10001 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT image FROM table_10002 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT image FROM table_10003 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT image FROM table_10004 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT image FROM table_10005 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;
$ cat t.sh
total=5
tablecount=10000
for (( i=1 ; i<=$total; i++))
do
    tableId=$(($tablecount + $i))
    echo "SELECT image FROM table_$tableId ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1;" | cat
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! but I still have a problem.

ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'table_' doesn't exist
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'table_id_' doesn't exist.

I can't seem to get the variable in.

Comment: Where is the _id_ Part coming from?

Comment: For testing sounds can remove everything after the first pipe and replace it with cat, then you should see the segment, also make sure to use a shell which works (I just confirmed it with bash, see above)

Comment: It works. I had a typo in there. Sorry and Thank you!